# How to truncate a lognormal distribution while keeping the log-mean and the log-standard deviation unchanged?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a random variable $x$ that follows a lognormal disbution: $\log(x)\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

I want to truncate this distribution over some interval $[a, b]$ with  $0<a<b<\infty$ while keeping $\mu$ and $\sigma$ unchanged.

Can someone explain how we do that or give a good reference that explains how to do it?

Comment: Start with some new parameters in the truncated distribution $\mu'$ and $\sigma'$. Calculate the new mean and variance and set this equal to the old mean and variance. Solve for  $\mu'$ and $\sigma'$. You will have a horrible mess of erf functions to deal with.

Comment: @user12049 I'm not quite sure to understand what you mean. I suppose you are refering to an algorithm to solve for the mean and the standar deviation. If so should I proceed by predefining the bounds of the interval? Do know a good reference on that?

Comment: There's a confusion: your title implies you want to preserve the first two moments of $x$, but the body says you want to do this for $\ln x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to illustrate with the normal distribution because it involves less typing but the same can be done for the log normal although all the expressions will be messier.
Parameterise the truncated distribution with $\mu'$ and $\sigma'$. So

$f(x|\mu',\sigma')=B(a,b,\mu',\sigma')exp(-(x-\mu')^2/2\sigma'^2)$

Where $B$ is the new normalization $B=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma'^2}(erf(\frac{b-\mu'}{\sqrt{2}\sigma'})-erf(\frac{a-\mu'}{\sqrt{2}\sigma'}))}$ (do check this.)

The new mean (call it M) is then given by a horrible looking expression involving $a,b,\mu',\sigma'$. Ditto for the variance (call it V).

Now set $M=\mu$ and $V=\sigma^2$ and solve for $\mu'$ and $\sigma'$ in terms of $a,b,\mu,\sigma$.

I am quite sure there will be no closed form expression for $\mu'$ and $\sigma'$.

Comment: Great I get it, thanks